# setConditionalFormatRules for another column google apps

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sirs, I'm stuck a bit with the format rule which can allows simultaneously added background in the different columns on the same row.

The script for condition applying is:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("AC10:AC");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenTextContains("Germany")
      .setBackground("#FF5300")
      .setRanges([range]) //ok, we set background in the "AC" column
      .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

Which approach should be implemented here to set the same background in the cell of the column "B", of the same row?

Comment: Could you share a sample spreadsheet and the desired output?

Comment: Sure, please simplified version:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sRnqwV36d2dK8uTUsDtcP40jiLmVV3BMQ2CgHuX5tC4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another rule that will use a custom formula to check the value of column **AC**.

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

  var range1 = sheet.getRange("AC10:AC");  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenTextContains("Germany")
      .setBackground("#FF5300")
      .setRanges([range1])
      .build()

  var range2 = sheet.getRange("B10:B");
  var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AC10="Germany"')
      .setBackground("#FF5300")
      .setRanges([range2])
      .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  rules.push(rule2)
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

### Reference:

- [whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#whenformulasatisfiedformula)

Comment: Do you know how need type this expression: 

`('=REGEXMATCH(AC10:AC;"\b(\w*German\w*)\b")') ` instead `('=AC10:AC="France"')`

If I type like above, the spreadsheet rules looks like on line below. 

`=REGEXMATCH(AC10:AC;"(w*Germanw*)")`  - the spreadsheet cut it out the regular expressions.

Comment: @AlexOn - You have to use escape character \. Try this formula: `=REGEXMATCH(AC10:AC;"\\b(\\w*German\\w*)\\b")`. Also, was my answer above able to fix your issue? If yes, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)